# I'm stuck in a loop of if top == bottom and if bottom == top

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a program that uses a 2D array. The user picks a row and column; if at least one element directly to the N S E or W matches, then it changes to '.'
I keep getting a segfault because, I'm fairly certain after various tests and problem solving, that it gets stuck in a loop of if top == bottom and bottom == top (or left and right). Since I need to check all four sides, I need to keep a check for both above and below.
Example:

```
0 - + + -
1 + + - -
2 - + - -
3 + + + -
4 - - + -
  0 1 2 3
```

If the user chooses (3,1) all the +'s would change to '.'
I would appreciate any suggestions on how to correct this problem. Code for this function is below. 
Thanks!

```
extern int bb_pop(BBoardPtr b, int r, int c) {
    char bal;
    int curr, curc;
    curr = r;
    curc = c;           
    if(b->board[curr][curc] == b->board[curr-1][curc] && curr != 0 && b->board[curr-1][curc] != '.') {
        curr--;
        bb_pop(b, curr, curc);
        b->board[curr][curc] = '.';
        count++;
        curr = r;
        curc = c;
        }
    if(b->board[curr][curc] == b->board[curr][curc-1] && curc !=0 && b->board[curr][curc] != '.') {
        curc--;
        bb_pop(b, curr, curc);
        b->board[curr][curc] = '.';
        count++;
        curr = r;
        curc = c;
        }
    if(b->board[curr][curc] == b->board[curr+1][curc] && curr < rows-1 && b->board[curr+1][curc] != '.') {
        curr++;
        bb_pop(b, curr, curc);
        b->board[curr][curc] = '.';
        count++;
        curr = r;
        curc = c;
        }
    if(b->board[curr][curc] == b->board[curr][curc+1] && curc<cols-1 && b->board[curr][curc] != '.') {
        curc++;
        bb_pop(b, curr, curc);
        b->board[curr][curc] = '.';
        count++;
        curr = r;
        curc = c;
        }
    if(count > 0) {
    b->board[r][c] = '.';
    }   

    printf("count %i\n", count);    /////////////fix count
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this at the top of your function:

```
charToFind = b->board[r][c];
b->board[r][c] = '.';
count = 1;
```

Then use `charToFind` instead of `board[curr][curc]`, and remove all `board[curr][curc]='.'` because your recursed functions will do that.  This should be what your main body looks like:

```
if (r != 0 && b->board[r-1][c] == charToFind)
    count += bb_pop(b, r-1, c);
if (r < rows-1 && b->board[r+1][c] == charTofind)
    count += bb_pop(b, r+1, c);

// Do the same thing for the c-1 and c+1 cases.
```

One thing to note is that if your board is big, you might recurse to a very large depth and overflow your stack.

Comment: Then it only changes a single element on each side. It doesn't go through the entire board checking for connecting, matching elements.

Comment: The curr and curc determine which char I'm checking - current row current column. So if the user says 3 1 it will start checking for matches at b->board[3][1]. By changing it to '.' right away, it will no longer match '+'. I'm really bad a recursion, so there is probably a better way that what I'm thinking, I just can't see it.

Comment: I get what you mean now. I can't add any new parameters to the function, but I will try adding a variable.

Comment: I'm on a tablet right now.  When I get to a computer I'll give a code sample of what I mean.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I am closer, but it doesn't get all of the matches. For example (0,2) doesn't change.
`if(b->board[curr-1][curc] == match && curr != 0) {                   
b->board[curr][curc] = '.';
curr--;
bb_pop(b, curr, curc);
count++;
curr = r;
curc = c;
}`

Comment: It's because you are changing curr and curc.  But you don't need those variables.  See my latest update.

Comment: You've made it seem so simple! :) I don't fully understand why it works though. It gets up to (0,1) then over to (0,2) why does it keep going back down to check left, right, and below? Or is the base case the original char changed so it has to keep rolling back to that? I am determined to understand [coding] recursion ... unless it makes my brain blow up and I die. Thank you for your extensive help.